# Opensuse 13.1 Gnome Desktop Region&Language won"t open after installing ibus

Tags: gnome, opensuse, input, ibus

i want to be able to write Kanji on my Opensuse system, so i followed this tutorial: http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2013/11/20/japanese-input-on-opensuse-linux-13-1-kde/

It does not work, because the ibus tray is not shown and it doesnt react to the key combination which should switch the input method. (yes, i added the input method in the ibus-settings and i enabled the show tray option.)

I read somewhere else, that ibus is not needed for the Gnome Desktop, one should be able to add input methods via system->Region&Languages. This does not open for me anymore though. Even after deinstall ibus and rebooting multiple times, i can not open system->Region&Languages (i used to be able to).

Does anyone know what might be the cause of this?

Johann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was to install ibus, ibus-anthy and anthy again, reboot and Update my Opensuse. After doing this, it worked.

I hope this helps anyone who stumbles across this weird bug in the future.